# AWS S3 - Video upload fails - JavaScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS JavaScript SDK in a Cordova application on Android and have set the configuration as below

```
AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
    region: Constants.region,
    httpOptions: {
        timeout: 1200000    //20 mins
    }
});
```

I'm able to upload images and text files of > 2MB size without issues. But the code always fails to upload video files of any size. Below are the error logs I'm getting

> PUT
>   https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/my-s3-bucket/files/VID-20170127-WA0017.mp4
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>
> PUT
>   https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/my-s3-bucket/files/VID-20170127-WA0017.mp4
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>
> PUT
>   https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/my-s3-bucket/files/VID-20170127-WA0017.mp4
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>
> PUT
>   https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/my-s3-bucket/files/VID-20170127-WA0017.mp4
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

It seems that the connection is reset after about 45-50 seconds inspite of the 20 min. timeout configuration

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am not sure about the reason why it happens, I have noticed that Android upload with https Url for large file fails with AWS S3. This has something to do with the https certificate of AWS because I haven't faced the issue with DigitialOcean Spaces.

So the solution here is trying uploading to non-https end-point.

Comment: How did you figure this out? Can you post some links to resources explaining this? I have posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596706/aws-s3-presignedpost-works-locally-but-fails-in-production-with-err-connection-r